# redis // redis-hash gets broken after passing 512 hash entries

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis, python-3.7, raspberry-pi4

I am just learning redis and wrote a little snippet to test connecting to, writing and reading from the redis db. Here is the script:

```
import random
import redis
from datetime import datetime

random.seed(1)
temps = "t"
humids = "h"

# create connection to redis server on default port 6379
POOL = redis.ConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=6379, decode_responses=True)
redis = redis.StrictRedis(connection_pool=POOL)

x = 0
while x < 513:
    y = random.random()
    now = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    # next line to cut off timestamp at millisecond precision
    # now = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
    redis.hset(temps, str(now)+"_t", y)
    redis.hset(humids, str(now)+"_h", y)
    x += 1

# print(redis.hgetall(sensor_log))
print("****************************************")
print("all temps:\n")
print(redis.hvals(temps))
print("****************************************")
print("all humids:\n")
print(redis.hvals(humids))
print("****************************************")
print("done")
```

The snippet (obviously) creates and writes a random number into two redis hashes.

Here's the weird behavior:

When I run through the loop **512** times (i. e. `while x < 512`) *the values in both hashes are **identical*** (as they should be).

But when I run through the loop **513** times (i. e. `while x < 513`) *the values in the two hashes are suddenly **different** from one another*. Sometimes the first value in the two hashes is identical but then all following values are different from one another.

Can anybody explain this?

Here's the environment I'm running this in:

- Raspberry Pi 4
- Python 3.7.3
- Redis server v=5.0.3 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.1.0 bits=32
  build=afa0decbb6de285f

[Screenshot of values in both hashes with 512 runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1ZXs.png)

[Screenshot of values in both hashes with 513 runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGE49.png)

[Pastebin of the values in the two hashes at 513 loop runs](https://pastebin.com/XmaVdCwm)

Comment: You uploaded the same image twice. Can you paste the actual text values? Are you sure they're different and not just in a different order?

Comment: That's it, david! Thank you for your very quick input and for solving this mystery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values in both hashes *are* identical - it's just that after more than 512 entries the order redis.hvals prints them out is suddenly different, thus leading to the visual mismatch on the output.

david got it right (see his first comment after the question).